# Webmail system that supports local mailspool

Tags: webmail

For a testing server we need access to local (HTML) emails which are stored in a single file in  `/var/spool/mail/foo-user`

I would like to use roundcube webmail but I think it supports only IMAP servers.

Is there a webmail client that supports access to the local mail files via webbrowser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any webmail clients that do this, so would go for installing an imap daemon such as courier or dovecot instead of trying to make things work without one.

Answer (score 0):

[Usermin](http://webmin.com/usermin.html) (part of Webmin) supports local mailspool.

Comment: Does webmin provide webmail?

Comment: @chicks With Usermin module, yes: http://webmin.com/usermin.html